# unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8 with Jhipster java11

Tags: maven, jhipster, java-11

I installed jhipster 6.9.1 and java jdk 11
I create new jhipster project and start it with mvnw
I get compile error unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8

#### The error log

```
Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[29,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[30,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[30,43] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[32,42] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[32,44] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[33,37] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[36,36] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[37,36] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[38,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[39,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/AbstractAuditingEntity_.java:[19,44] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/AbstractAuditingEntity_.java:[19,46] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/AbstractAuditingEntity_.java:[20,44] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/AbstractAuditingEntity_.java:[20,46] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/PersistentAuditEvent_.java:[19,38] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/PersistentAuditEvent_.java:[19,41] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/PersistentAuditEvent_.java:[20,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/PersistentAuditEvent_.java:[22,36] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/PersistentAuditEvent_.java:[23,39] unmappable character (0xDD) for encoding UTF-8
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[29,39] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[29,41] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[30,39] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[30,43] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[30,50] <identifier> expected
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[32,42] illegal character: '\ufffd'
[ERROR] /C:/Users/metin.bulak/Desktop/jh/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/app/domain/User_.java:[32,44] illegal character: '\ufffd'

[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: Can you explain what the real question is? Cause the error message tells already what the problem is? The generated code produces unmappable characters?

Comment: Jhipster compatible with jdk11 but I can not compile with it due to character error. Idont know how I can solve it

Comment: The issue seems to be only in classes generated by hibernate-jpamodelgen maven plugin which is used by JHipster for entity filtering, so maybe there's something that can be done in pom.xml and which is related to  in your your environment. Which character encoding is configured in your Windows env? Alternatively,you could disable entity filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pom.xml, you can change charset 'UTF-8' to 'Windows-1252'. It will get a solution.